# VBA Workbooks.open "Compile error: Argument not optional"

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use the

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= [...]
```

method to access some data within a **for each** loop using a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Routine. I've done this successfully in a few other Macros but for some reason, in all modules within this file (I've tried rebooting the machine etc.), I receive the message "Compile error: Argument not optional" for the code on that line. Other workbooks don't throw up errors there.

My research into the problem hasn't yielded anything tailored to this particular situation - I think that maybe I need to use Set somewhere to force VBE to recognize the object? Hopefully a more experienced user will be able to recognize some classic situations where this might occur. The only clue I have for now is that the VBE doesn't seem to recognize "workbooks" as a keyword, as it's not capitalizing the first letter.

Any help would be much appreciated.

C

Comment: Apparently you have something else called `Workbooks` in that workbook? A variable, a custom class?

Comment: GSerg,

Thanks for your reply. I had imported another function into the module built by somebody else with the intention of modifying elements of the code to fit in with mine. Inside was a sub called... yep you guessed it ("workbook").

Thanks for your help, hopefully the next question I ask will be a more interesting one.

Comment: I can't see where on the page where to mark as resolved? Will come back and have a look

Comment: You can't accept it because I didn't post it as an aswer. I will now :)

Comment: In the future, click on the `Workbooks` variable and type `Shift-F2`, or right-click on the `Workbooks` variable and choose `Definition`. This will show you the thing that is complaining about non-optional arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is something else in the workbook called `Workbooks` (variable, class, function), and because it has more local scope it gets found before the the actual `Workbooks` object.

You can either rename the offending object or access `Workbooks` in a more qualified way:

```
Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:= [...]
```

Comment: P.S. Sorry to blow up your answer on the other question with my quick edit. Great minds thinking alike and all that. It was striking how similar the queries were.

Comment: @ErikE NP, I actually admired the similarity more than potential rep, too